How to troubleshoot wrong SSL cert for SMTP connection
i have a mailcow mail server, everything works fine including sending and receiving mails. However when i try to setup my account in Thunderbird, it automatically finds the Configuration needed. After adding the Account i get a Security Exception that says the TLS certificate is invalid (Wrong Site). Looking into the Certificate it uses my bitwarden.domain.com cert instead.
How am i able to troubleshoot this issue and how severe is the issue?
I will provide any information needed, currently im not sure where to start. I also tried openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect mail.domain.com:465 it returns: CONNECTED(00000003)

Welcome to Serverfault. Unfortunately we can only answer question if you explain the problem adequately. You didn't tell us what SMTP server you are using. You did not provide the configuration. You said that sending an receving mail works then proceed to tell us that it doesn't work with Thunderbird. You might want to review what you have presented here.

465 is (submission) SMTP with implicit (SSL/)TLS so must NOT have -starttls smtp on s_client. If you instead use or try 587 that DOES use -starttls smtp. I do not know which Thunderbird uses either in general or in your environment.
